# XSD schema validation constraints

Tags: xml, xsd, constraints, unique, xsd-validation

There is a xml structure as follows

Is it possible in XSD to block "dataRef" element referencing it's parent "data/dataRef" attribute value (basically a child can't match parents value constraint).
Is it possible to make two way relationships mandatory as seen in the "order/item" of "AAAA" which has a reference to "AEAR" "data" element but that element does not have a "AAAA" data item referencing "data" "AAAA"

```
<data dataRef="AAAA">
    <order>
        <!-- this should not be allowed to reference its own parent element -->
        <item>
            <dataRef>AAAA</dataRef>
        </item>
        <item>
            <dataRef>BASA</dataRef>
        </item>
        <item>
            <dataRef>AEAR</dataRef>
        </item>
    </order>
</data>
<data dataRef="AEAR">
    <order>
        <!-- since this is referenced from data/@dataRef="AAAA" there should be an element pointing back to "dataRef" "AAAA" as it is a two way relationship -->
        <item>
            <dataRef>BASA</dataRef>
        </item>
    </order>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1):

As is so often the answer when people want to express complex constraints in XSD, the answer is that you can do it in XSD 1.1 with assertions, but not in XSD 1.0.